# GMT retorna -0306 ao invés de -0300, qual o motivo?

Tags: java, data, timezone

```
Locale ptBR = new Locale("pt", "BR");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy", ptBR);
SimpleDateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ");
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(ptBR);
String data = "31/12/1900";
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(data));
iso.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(iso.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Saida: `1900-12-31T00:00:00.000-0306`

Alguém sabe me explicar por que o GMT retorna -0306 ao invés de -0300?

Comment: Vai ver seu computador criou um fuso só pra ele :) Ou você deu cachaça pra ele :) Não tenho a menor ideia se isto pode acontecer em "condições normais". Não reproduzi: http://ideone.com/KLgcdr

Comment: Eu reproduzi, pode ter algo a ver com a descontinuidade temporal, algo similar a [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/1964435)

Comment: Horário de verão? o.õ

Comment: Experimente com uma data recente. Se for por causa de leap-seconds a diferença é pra sumir

Comment: Jon Skeet to the rescue! http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/916193

Comment: @Bacco então esse é o tal jon skeet que falaram no chat kkkk

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Aqui tem um resumo das habilidades dele http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134

Comment: Qual é o retorno de `calendar.getTimeZone()`?

Comment: @bfavaretto o retorno é `Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 BRT 1900`

Comment: @Bacco com datas recentes não acontece.

Comment: Verifiquei que o problema acontece até "31/12/1913", depois disso normaliza.

Comment: Relacionado: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/recife?year=1913 e http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/salvador?year=1913 Só que em outras cidades do Brasil isso não acontece, fora que o ajuste de salvador foi diferente do de recife. Tá difícil de entender...

Comment: @Math Acho que entendi, vide resposta (meu dia de Skeet!!!).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Até 1914, o Brasil utilizava o [LMT (Local Mean Time)](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html) como referência de horário. A partir desse ano, passou a adotar diferentes zonas horárias, com diferenças em horas redondas em relação ao UTC. O LMT é baseado na longitude, por isso havia diferenças de frações de hora de uma localidade para outra.

Com a regulamentação das zonas horárias oficiais por [decreto em 1913](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/decreto/Antigos/D10546.htm) (vigente a partir de 1/1/1914), as pequenas diferenças entre as localidades foram normalizadas, como se vê na tabela constante de tal decreto:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que em 1/1/1914 o horário de São Paulo deveria ser corrigido em 6m35s. Acredito que seja essa diferença que o seu código está mostrando.

Comment: Fazendo isso: `System.out.println(new Date("01/01/1914"));` eu tenho isso: `Thu Jan 01 00:06:28 BRT 1914`, se mudar para `02/01/1914` ele se acerta: `Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 BRT 1914`

Comment: Pois é, o decreto fala em 6m35s, mas de fato o [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo) (escolher período 1900-1924) indica 6m28s. Não sei o motivo dessa diferença.

Comment: De onde você tirou essa imagem? Tá escrito _"atrazar"_, argh! Fora o "Goyaz", "Cuyabá"...

Comment: Em 1913 escrevia-se assim :) A imagem é um screenshot da versão atual do decreto no site do governo (por isso o *strike*, a maioria do que está ali já foi superado por legislação posterior).

Comment: Vou me certificar perguntando no [portuguese.se], rs..

Answer (score -3):

Oi @Luan, o código abaixo serve pra você?

```
Locale ptBR = new Locale("pt", "BR");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy", ptBR);
SimpleDateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssX");
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(ptBR);
String data = "31/12/1900";
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(data));
iso.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(iso.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: Você só capou os últimos dígitos...

Comment: Não quero uma opção para remover os últimos dígitos, quero entender o motivo.